# Creating a new column in a dataframe based on the values on another column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So I have the dataframe:

```
id   Name   Score   
313  John    600
415  Zack    800
990  Harry   300
...   ...    ...
```

What I want to do is to create a new column in this dataframe that sees if the score is greater or less than the next and places 1 if it is greater and 0 if it is less. What I want looks like this:

```
id   Name   Score  Operator
313  John    600      1
415  Zack    800      0
990  Harry   300      1
...   ...    ...      .
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `Operator` field contain all 1s as each Score is bigger than the previous? Apologies if I am not understanding properly.

Comment: Sorry I made an error, I just corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate a Boolean column and then convert to `int`:

```
df['Operator'] = df['Score'].diff(-1).lt(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: what does the lt(0) do

Comment: @Afzal, It stands for "less than". So you get a Boolean series depending with `True` when a value is less than `0`. Use `gt` if you need "greater than", `le` for "less than or equal to", `ge` for "greater than or equal to".